# How to read integers from a file which have characters mixed with them in JAVA?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file which contains something like this - 23+3 
i have to do the math and write the ans in a different text file.
i have tried with scan.nextInt() method.but shows exception when scanning "+"
any help here with ignoring the other chars ??

Comment: Read the line as a String, then parse it through a utility method to get your result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex to match for numbers like,

`String regex = "[0-9]+";`
or

`String regex = "\\d+";`

Where the + means "one or more" and \d means "digit".

Note: the "double slash" gives you one slash. "\d" gives you: \d

Pass the regex to pattern :
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);`
and then look for a match in your input string
`Matcher m1 = p.matcher(inputString);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you only have an addition operator. You could split on the `+` symbol.

```
String[] arr = "23+3".split("+"); // returns ['23', '3']
```

Now you will iterate through your String array, convert each entry to an Integer, and sum the entire array.

You can extend this approach to use subtraction/multiplication/division etc. However you may want to look up as [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Take a look at this StackOverflow answer:

[How to construct an abstract syntax tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721553/how-to-construct-an-abstract-syntax-tree)